# Подгрузка изображения для CSS, чтобы на первом круге не мелькал белый экран

Tags: html, css, анимация, webkit

Где то видел такое решение, не могу теперь найти, в мета картинки подгружаются, кто знает?

Comment: Сделай фон подходящего цвета.